# ffmpeg 2 LAN connection

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming

I use ffmpeg for send stream to rtmp server and I had 2 LAN connections to my computer I want ffmpeg to select connection (for different IP address output from each connection).

How can I set command for this requirement ?

Comment: Are the destinations on the local LANs directly, or are they remote (or one of each)? From what I gather, most protocols in FFmpeg don’t have an option to select the source interface, so you would have to rely on the kernel making the right choice.

Comment: No the destinations on the public server (the same destination server) I use ffmpeg on Windows

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1004697/48624